# au point de vue (de)

Tags: expressions, prépositions

Je lis une ressource en ligne mais je suis un peu sceptique quant aux recommendations.

On dit que ceci serait fautif :

> au point de vue congés

On conseille au lieu :

> au point de vue **des** congés

Une recherche sur Google ne semble pas remonter grand-chose. Apparemment, *de* est *de jure* dans l'expression semblable « [sur le plan (de)](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3879) ». Tandis que côté « côté », on ne l'emploie pas (*côté + nom*).

S'agit-il du pédantisme ou cette ressource a-t-elle raison même pour la langue de tous les jours ?

Comment: Je suis plutôt d'accord avec la recommandation, l'ellision n'apporte rien et rend la phrase un peu trop informelle, ça fait pas très professionnel.

Comment: *Googler ceci ne semble relever que peu* : Il manque la fin de la phrase ?

Comment: @jlliagre Merci ... j'ai essayé de traduire « doesn't turn up much » mais je suppose que cette ellipse ne fonctionne pas en français ?

Comment: C'est vrai, l'ellipse ne fonctionne pas ici. Ce pourrait être: *(Une recherche sur) Google ne permet pas de clarifier beaucoup le sujet*, *ne remonte pas grand chose* ou *n'apporte pas beaucoup de clarification*. Le verbe *googler* est peu utilisé en France.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci beaucoup. J'ai choisi la version qui me semble la plus familière ...

Comment: Or in conversation, I'd phrase the idea as follows, dropping "sur": "Même après *une recherche Google*, je n'en sais toujours pas (beaucoup) plus sur la question pour autant."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est du français relâché où *congés* est un peu utilisé comme un adjectif.

cf. [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/point%20de%20vue) :

> *Fam*. [Suivi d'un subst. non déterminé] *Nous sommes déjà toutes réunies dans les classes quand ces demoiselles descendent enfin, et elles en prennent à leur aise aussi, au point de vue toilette !* (Colette, *Cl. école*, 1900, p.263). *Toutes [ces régions] étaient riches en boeufs sauvages donc intéressantes, au point de vue chasse* (Maran, *Batouala*, 1921, p.116).

Une expression plus soutenue pourrait être :

> En ce qui concerne les congés...

Une expression familière équivalente et probablement plus courante est :

> Question congés...